# Unable to convert uri to Bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework

I am trying to convert a google doc into a bitmap so I can perform OCR within it.
I am however getting the errors:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/acc=4;doc=14882: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> E/ReadFile: Bitmap must be non-null
>
> E/CropTest: Failed to read bitmap

Code:

```
/**
 * Fires an intent to spin up the "file chooser" UI and select an image.
 */
public void performFileSearch(View view) {

  // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
  // browser.
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

  // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
  // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

  // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
  // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
  // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
  // it would be "*/*".
  intent.setType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");

  startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData){

  if(requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
    Uri uri = null;
    if(resultData != null){
      uri = resultData.getData();
      Log.i(TAG, "Uri" + uri.toString());

      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uri:" + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      IMGS_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/TesseractSample/imgs";
      prepareDirectory(IMGS_PATH);
      prepareTesseract();
      startOCR(uri);
    }
  }
}

//Function that begins the OCR functionality.
private void startOCR(Uri imgUri) {
  try {

    Log.e(TAG, "Inside the startOCR function");
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // 1 - means max size. 4 - means maxsize/4 size. Don't use value <4, because you need more memory in the heap to store your data.
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    //  FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(imgUri));
    Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imgUri);
    // bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outStream);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath());
    // bitmap = toGrayscale(bitmap);

    //The result variable will hold whatever is returned from "extractText" function.
    result = extractText(bm);

    //Creating the intent to go to the CropTest
    Intent intentToCropTest = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CropTest.class);
    intentToCropTest.putExtra("result",result);
    startActivity(intentToCropTest);

    //Setting the string result to the content of the TextView.
    // textView.setText(result);

  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the item in that location?

Comment: I believe so, but the errors make it look like it is not. I am not sure how it is null.

Comment: How do you expect us to help without seeing source code of `startOCR`? Extract the failing part into method and add it's source to the question.

Comment: I apologize, I thought I had pasted it within @user1643723

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to treat Android `Uri` as file path. Don't do that. Instead retrive a ContentResolver instance and use it to convert Uri to stream:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = context.getContentResolver()
    .openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
InputStream is = fd.createInputStream();
```

If AssetFileDescriptor is not supported (you get null or an Exception happens), try a more direct route:

```
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream();
```

There is also another super-duper powerful content-type-aware approach, which existed for ages,  but was [re-discovered by Google's own developers around the time of Android N release](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html). It requires a lot more infrastructure on ContentProvider side (may not be supported in older versions of Google Services):

```
ContentResolver r = getContentResolver();

String[] streamTypes = r.getStreamTypes(uri, "*/*");

AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = r.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(
                    uri,
                    streamTypes[0],
                    null);

InputStream is = descriptor.createInputStream();
```

Then use obtained stream to create Bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Comment: I see. Should this be performed within the startOCR function?

Comment: I have elaborated on that part

Comment: Yes I see it now. I will test this out. Hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: Although it did not work for me specifically, I am sure it will work for others. I believe it might be due to the MIME type of google docs.

Comment: Have you tried all 3 approaches? Do you still get the same log messages?